# Trouble connecting to blob storage account through SFTP

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, sftp, azure-logic-apps, azure-storage-account

I am trying to connect to my Storage Account through SFTP with my Logic App. SFTP is enabled on my Storage Account and I have set up a local user. When inputting my information to establish a connection I'm receiving a "Bad Gateway" error. Below is a picture of the error and how I'm inputting the information.

[image]

Is there something I'm entering wrong here?

Some additional information:

I thought it was a possible firewall issue even though my Storage Account was set up to be accessed from all networks. I changed that to accept connections from selected virtual networks and IP addresses. I added all Runtime outgoing IP addresses and Connector outgoing IP addresses from my logic app that I'm trying to connect from, to the firewall. Although I'm still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You have given wrong username. Username should be given like this :

```
storageaccountname.conatinername.username
```

I have  created user for container.

**`Design:`**

[image]

Then it got created :

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked. This seems to work even without the container name specified. Another thing I had to do was make my container accessible from all networks again. Even though I'd specified all "Runtime outgoing IP addresses" and "Connector outgoing IP addresses" from my Logic App. There is one more set of IP addresses from my logic app I didn't add which were the "Access endpoint IP addresses"- would this have been the culprit or likely something else?

Comment: You need to use Logic app workflow from VM which is connected to Vnet, And the same Vnet should be connected to  Storage account also, then it will work.